# Phalcon pass object from controller into view

Tags: phalcon, volt

I'm new in phalcon and I wonder what is correct way to pass some data from controller into view from database. For example

```
$lastOrder = LeaOrder::findFirst([   
    'conditions' => 'user_id = ?1',
    'order' => "id DESC",
    'bind'       => [
        1 => $userID,
    ]
]);


$this->view->setVars([
    'lastOrder'=> $lastOnGoingOrder,
]);
```

Can I show data for the user from LeaOrder object like `{{lastOrder->name}}` or should I make `toArray()` before passing object into view and then `{{lastOrder[name]}}` or this doesnt matter like I handle this? thank you for all advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even use the quick syntax:

```
$this->view->lastOrder = LeaOrder::findFirst([   
    'conditions' => 'user_id = ?1',
    'order' => "id DESC",
    'bind'       => [
        1 => $userID,
    ]
]);
```

In the view:

```
// To access object properties
{{ lastOrder.name }}

// To access array keys
{{ lastOrder['name'] }}
```

Phalcon ORM returns Model objects, however if you really need an array you can call the `->toArray()` method on your object.

I would suggest you reading this section from docs: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/volt **Filters** - section is really useful as well.

**UPDATE:** Debugging ORM results.
When dumping ORM result you see tons of information because of DI (dependency injection) that Phalcon is using. One easy way to debug is call `->toArray()` on your model. This way you will only see model properties.

```
$this->view->order = LeaOrder::findFirstById(82);
print_r($this->view->order->toArray();
```

**But please note:** `toArray()` is converting your object into array, but since you are not assigning it and just doing it inside the `print_r` for debug purpose, later you will use it as object in your code/template.

**UPDATE 2:** Handy function for Phalcon debugging

```
function d($what)
{
    if (is_object($what) AND method_exists($what, 'toArray')) {
        $what = $what->toArray();
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($what);
    die('</pre>');
}

// Usage:
$this->view->order = LeaOrder::findFirstById(82);
d($this->view->order);
```

Comment: One more thing, when {{dump(lastOrder)}} I get tons of information with my result like database passwords details, there is no way to catch this by the users right (sorry for stupid question)?

Comment: Updated above :)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. One more thing, should I stay with obejct or array while presenting data to the user? which way should be this done ?

Comment: It is your personal preference. In most of the cases I use Objects and Array only if I need to process data or pass it as json somewhere. Technically the array conversion will cost you some "server resources" :) Also I prefer the object (dot syntax) in my Volt templates.

Comment: Hey again! Updated answer with my handy debug function. If you pass ORM object it converts automatically to array for quick debug preview :)